# a reference for Kummer theory, with proofs ? 

Tags: kummer-theory, nt.number-theory, abelian-varieties

What is a standard reference for Kummer theory of semi-Abelian varieties ? 
I need a complete exposition with detailed proofs. Also in prime characteristic,
although I am not sure what the statement there exactly is.

Below I give an example of what I mean by Kummer theory
in zero characteristic.

> Let $G = A\times L$ be a product of
>   an Abelian variety by a torus L so
>   that  after a finite extension of k it
>   satisfies Poincare's complete
>   reducibility theorem (as a variety
>   over k).
>
> Let $l$ be a prime. Let $G_l=\{ x \in
> > G(\bar k) : \exists n l^nx=0\}$ be the
>   $l$-torsion of G. For a point $P\in
> > G(\bar k)$, let  $G_P$ be the smallest
>   algebraic subgroup of G containing P,
>   i.e. Zariski closure of subgroup
>   ${\Bbb Z}P$ of $G$, and let $G_P$  be
>   its connected component through the
>   origin,
>
> $$\zeta_l(P) : Gal(\bar
> > k/k(G_l,P))\longrightarrow T_l(A\times
> > L)$$ $$\sigma \mapsto
> > \sigma(P_l)-P_l$$ where $P_l$ is  a
>   compatible sequence of  division
>   points, $P_1 = P$.  By Kummer theory I
>   mean the statement that ([Bertrand,
>   Theorem 2]) the image of  of the map
>   $\prod \zeta_l$ is of finite index  in
>   $NT(G_P^o)$ for a large $N$.

Above is taken from  Bertrand, D.: Galois representations and transcendental numbers. 
In: New advances in transcendence theory (Durham, 1986), Cambridge University Press, Cambridge (1988); but proofs there are a little too sketchy for me. 13.
 Ribet, K.: Kummer theory on extensions of varieties by tori. Duke Math. J. 46(4), (1979)
has a slightly weaker statement.